# How do I run a function on ngOnInit() only once and not again upon returning back from another routerLink?

Tags: angular, ngoninit, lifecycle-hook

**`HomeComponent`**

```
ngOnInit()
{
    console.log('loaded');
    this.retrieveData();
}

retrieveData()
{
    // this.dataService.getData().subscribe(...);
}
```

I am retrieving data when the component loads. When the user clicks on another `routerLink`, for example, `SettingsComponent` and returns back to the `HomeComponent`, the function of course, is called again because the component has loaded again. But Everytime I return back to the component, it makes the function call again which creates too many unwanted HTTP requests. I need to prevent this and make sure the function is called only the first time. How do I do this? Should I use some other component lifecycle hook?

Comment: I think that should be the desired behaviour. Otherwise your data wouldn't change until the user closes the app.

Comment: That is true. But if I am using interval in my observable (say the data loads once every second) and if I go to SettingsComponent and come back to HomeComponent, it creates another instance of the interval so I'm making two requests a second and overtime if the process repeats, I am sending 50 requests a second.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Okay I see you are using a [service](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/tutorial/toh-pt4.html) to load the data which is a good way.

Then you can simply cache the data somewhere and when you come back to a component check the cache for this data. I think you can store the data directly in your service which will keep it in the memory or you can put it in the [localStorage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage)

So first option would look like:

**data.service.ts**

```
export class DataService {

    private data: any[];

    setData(data:any[]){
        this.data = data;
    } 

    getData(){
        return this.data || [];
    }

    hasData(){
        return this.data && this.data.length;    
    }  

    getData(){
        // your implementation here 
    }
}
```

then inside **HomeComponent**

```
retrieveData(){
    if(this.dataService.hasData()){
         // this will get the data which was previously stored in the memory
         // and there will be no HTTP request
         let data = this.dataService.getData();
         // do something with data now ...
    }else{
        // old code 
        this.dataService.getData().subscribe(response => {
            // but this time safe the data for future use
            this.dataService.setData(response.data);   
        }, error => {
            // handle errors
        });
    }
}
```

**IMPORTANT**: if using this approach you should make your service global when declaring it in **app.module.ts** -> **providers**

```
@NgModule({
    declarations: [
        AppComponent
    ],
    imports: [
        BrowserModule,
        FormsModule,
        HttpModule
    ],
    providers: [
        DataService   <---------- SEE HERE
    ],
    bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

and then not doing this:

```
@Component({
    selector: 'home',
    templateUrl: '...',
    styleUrls: ['...'],
    providers: [
        DataService     <---- THEN DON'T put in component's providers
    ]
})
export class HomeComponent{ ... }
```

**=============================================**

**The localStorage approach**

**HomeComponenet**

```
retrieveData()
{
    let data = localStorage.getItem('yourDataName');
    if (data === null){
        // old code 
        this.dataService.getData().subscribe(response => {
            // but this time safe the data for future use in localStorage
            localStorage.setItem('yourDataName', response.data); 
        }, error => {
            // handle errors
        });
    } else {
        // seems that you already loaded this data 
        // do something with this data ...
    }
}
```

Both approaches has the limitation that you can't work with huge amounts of data, of course if you don't want to blow the browsers of users that are using your app :)

Comment: Thanks for explaining so well. This seems like a very good solution to my problem. I'l try this and let you know what happens.

Comment: I'm glad that it is understandable. In both approaches you can have the control when you want to reload the data again from the server

Comment: I tried the first solution and it's exactly what I wanted. Now that I'm storing the data in the memory and not retrieving it every time, a lot of functions in the app now respond faster than before. Really appreciate it, my friend.